# What do the "S", "T" and "Pr" icons that appear in the "auto completion box" in Swift playground mean?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

## Question

What do the "S", "T" and "Pr" icons that appear in the "auto completion box" in Swift playground mean? Are there other kinds?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

## Answer (for search engine indexing)

```
C  : Classes
Pr : Protocols
f  : Functions
S  : Structs
U  : Unions
E  : Enums
T  : Types
V  : Globals
```

Comment: In the future, rather than putting the answer in the question, you should just [post a separate answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Rob : Well, the answer was from matt, and the credits go to him. Since his answer is picture-based, I re-typed it for search engine indexing. For example, if someone Googles for "swift f functions s t e", this post should appear in the search result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the same abbreviations that appear in the Symbol navigator, where they are defined for you (as the attached screen shot shows):

[image]

Thus, as the table tells you, C means class, Pr means protocol, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also suggest how to display a list of them, as shown in your screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: The screenshot _is_ a list of them. I've answered your question, I believe. You asked what they meant and I told you what they meant.

Comment: Okay, I found it. For those who can't, try pressing `⌘2`, or `View` -> `Navigators` -> `Show Symbol Navigator`. You may need to configure the view by enabling / disabling the options at the bottom-left corner (the "C", "Document" and "M" icons).